# Laser Positioning on robot

Tags: ros, navigation, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a laser pushed forward to the front of my robot. I hit stuff when I navigate, so I'm trying to fix that... How do I make the tf understand the laser is pushed forward?

Also, I want to reconfigure the footprint of the robot. Any help?

---

So I found this launch file:

```
<launch>
    <!-- publish the static transform from the center of the robot to the laser rangefinder (required for slam_gmapping) -->
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0 0.1778 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100" />
</launch>
```

Any idea how to adjust it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38280/laser-positioning-on-robot/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to either use a static_transform_publisher as [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) shows or create a URDF file as [these tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials) show.

**Edit**: You can find the documentation for static_transform_publisherer [here](http://ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher). The numbers specify the position of your sensor in the robot's base, format is x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3